# DWR3 not returning a valid JSON response

Tags: json, dwr

I have been trying to ajax a JSON response containing apostrophe through DWR, in a java method which is returning the response as a java map. The response is printing correctly in the server without any escape character(\), however when I try to ajax it via DWR3 it returns the JSON including the escape character(\).

The returned response is not a valid JSON response after the DWR call which is as below,

```
{  
   "reply":{  
      "airlines":[  
         {  
            "airlineDetails":{  
               "airportCode":"WIC",
               "name":"Wick John O\'Groats"
            },
            "cityDetails":{  
               "code":"WIC",
               "name":"Wick"
            },
            "countryDetails":{  
               "code":"GB",
               "name":"United Kingdom"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried replacing the apostrophe with the respective unicode character \u0027 and this is responding with the same escape character in the response.

Comment: Was going through the link http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/browser/util/escapeHtml.html

 I hope we are not using the dwr util in our server, so not sure if the escapeHtml is the only option to resolve this.

Comment: We receive the JSON response from a webservice call as a JAVA string then converted that to a java map using object mapper to suit DWR.